# Runnng Hadoop Application Remotely

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I want to run a hadoop application through java

If I run my application with commmand `haddoop jar` inside the cluster everything works fine. But I need to run the job remotely.

I've set the configuration for the resource manager and othe properties like this:

```
        jobConf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address", "192.168.111.9:8032");
        jobConf.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn");

        jobConf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://192.168.111.9:8020");
        //If not set throws an error regarding to unable to write on /tmp/hadoop-yarn
        jobConf.set("yarn.app.mapreduce.am.staging-dir", "/user");
        jobConf.set("mapreduce.app-submission.cross-platform", "true");
        jobConf.set("mapreduce.application.classpath", "$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/*:$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/lib/*:$MR2_CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_CLIENT_CONF_DIR:$HADOOP_CONF_DIR:$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/*:$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/lib/*:$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/*:$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/lib/*:$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/*:$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/lib/*");
        String target = "variables-hadoop-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar";
        jobConf.set("mapreduce.job.jar", target)
```

But every time I run the application never gets to resource manager, and the log says:

```
2017-01-25 19:36:09,998 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8030
2017-01-25 19:36:11,032 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8030. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

And keeps trying for a long time

Then I tried to set property

`jobConf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address", "192.168.111.9:8030 ");`

But another error is thrown

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port authority: 192.168.111.9:8030  (configuration property 'yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address')
```

**Is there any "easy way" to do this?** It's hard to discover every single property that should be set.

I'm running on a cluster with Cloudera - Hadoop 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've added a space to the end of the scheduler address, that's why you get the `IllegalArgumentException`

Change:

```
jobConf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address", "192.168.111.9:8030 ");
//                                                                       ^
```

to

```
jobConf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address", "192.168.111.9:8030");
//                                                                       ^
```

Comment: Yes... that was the problem. It's hard to see from the log Thanks.